# How to disable Cognito user after exceeding the unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an angular app, which uses AWS Cognito for authentication and I want to disable users after 5 unsuccessful attempts. There is a method `adminDisableUser()` but it requires admin credentials.
I am thinking of Lambda function, which should be triggered on *Pre sign-up* or *Pre authentication*, which should check if the attempt is successful or not. If it is unsuccessful it should increment the value of a custom attribute, for example `custom:failedAttempts`. If the value is equal to 5, the user should be disabled. The lambda can be executed with admin permission, so it that it can use the `adminUpdateUserAttributes()` and `adminDisableUser()`
However, I am not really sure how this can happen, because I am new to AWS lambdas and IAM.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cognito already rate limits the login endpoint to prevent brute force login attacks, although from my own experience it seems like it could be tightened up a bit. I think your proposed plan is a dangerous approach, since a malicious user could send in 5 bad login attempts for any user and lock them out.

If you really want to lock out the user intend to require manual intervention to re-enable to user, your approach should work. The Pre-Authentication and Post-Authentication triggers are probably what you are looking for. in Pre-authentication (fired before successful authentication), look up the user (since the user is not authenticated, using adminGetUser, and increment a custom attribute with adminUpdateUserAttributes. If the incremented value is greater than your allowed number of login failures, then disable the user using adminDisableUser

In Post-authentication (fired after successful login), reset the custom attribute to zero.